# Why Am I Getting An Error In PrintF?

Tags: java

I am getting an error in PrintF in the following java code.
**The Error Is :**

> The method printf(String, Object[ ]) in the type PrintStream is not
>   applicable for the arguments  (String, int)

**The Code Is :**

```
    public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.printf("The value i is: %d", i); 
        }
      }
   }
```

Why am I getting this error? I think I have written the code correct but why is eclipse considering it as an error ? What can i do to remove this error ? I have 64 Bit JDK 8 | Windows 7|Eclipse 4.3 Kelper |

Comment: What version of Java is this being compiled under?

Comment: JDK 8 64 Bit Windows 7

Comment: Anchit, if you're using an IDE, be sure that its Java compliance level is actually st at JDK 8 and not a lower value. This is likely why autoboxing is failing.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Yes I am using eclipse. I l try you solution.

Comment: Go into the following menus: Window -- Preferences -- Java -- Compiler and set the compiler compliance to Java 8.

Comment: Then check the properties of your project by right-clicking it in package explorer. You may have a different setting for the project.

Comment: there is no option of java 8 . The highest is java 1.7 in preferences...shall i set to 1.7

Comment: Then choose 1.7. Autoboxing will work with this compiler level.